# get permutations of each line in file

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I have a text file that looks like this

```
1. El Paso there Yakima Sacramento Riverside Fresno Rialto Denver Fordham
2. Westminster Austin Tiverton Greensboro Riverside Fresno Rialto Denver Fordham
3. Westminster Lakeview Miami Tiverton Riverside Fresno Rialto Denver Fordham
4. Lakeview Austin Tiverton Greensboro Riverside Fresno Rialto Denver Fordham
5. Easton Yakima Miami St. Louis Riverside Fresno Rialto Denver Fordham
```

I want to print the permutations of every line(n = 9, k= 9), so that I end up with 1814400 total lines (362880 x 5).Here is my code

```
import itertools

with open('12round.txt') as file:
> for line in file:
> perms = itertools.permutations(line, 9)
> for i in perms:
> print(' '.join(i))`
```

however it prints like letters and its just weird. Please help! I've been trying to find a solution and I'm getting a headache not finding anything thanks in advance.

this is as far as my script writing goes.

Comment: To clarify, you want the permutations of the words in each line, not the characters, right?  So, you need to first split each line into words.  You forgot to do that.

Comment: yes, I want to get permutations of each word in line one, then move onto line two. I'm doing it manually where I'm deleting and pasting each line, then running the script. How would I split each line into words?

Comment: `word_list = line.split()`

Comment: How do you know the token is `El Paso`, rather than that string being 2 tokens `El`, and `Paso`?

Answer (score 2):

if I understood your problem correctly, you read a line, you need to get the words of this line, then you do your permutations accordingly,
I guess your problem is that you are not removing the white spaces and taking the words then running itertools.permutations.
Here is a sample code: (I took the n=9, k=9 according to your example)

```
import itertools
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        perms = itertools.permutations(line.split(), 9) 
        for i in range(9):
           for perm in perms:
             print(' '.join(perm))
```